# Vertex Set Optimization

Tags: computational-complexity, linear-programming

I have the following problem:

Min $c^Tx$

Subject to:

$Ax = b$

$x >= 0 $

Where A is an M x N matrix:

But rather a single solution I would like to know the first K best solutions where $1<= k <= u$ where u is the number of points on the polyhedron $Ax = b$

For example, if k = 2

I would like to know the first optimal point and then second most optimal point.

Can this be done in polytime with respect to the data used to present the problem and the value of k:

Comment: Any thoughts on your part? If you just post your homework question as is, you are not likely to receive much help.

Comment: It's not a homework question

Comment: I'm guessing running ellipsis with different initial points is a good idea

Comment: It's just a suggestion. I've found that people are more than willing to help you find the answer, but that they expect you to do the actual legwork. If you think the ellipses approach is a good one, they try it and see if it works. If it doesn't, asking for help in understanding why it didn't work would probably help you to better understand the problem and find the correct answer. I am not an ueberuser and am still a student myself, so take my advice for what it's worth.